# javascript id select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that someone made for me. I am kind of a noob at raw javascript. I use jquery quite often so I have been spoiled. Right now the function runs when someone clicks anywhere on the page because the `document` selector is used to trigger the function. I want the function to run when a specific id is clicked. I do have jquery installed as well. Anyone have any suggestions?

**addEvent('#id', 'click', function(){** does not work

**addEvent(document.getElementById("id"), 'click', function(){** does not work

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) { 
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn; 
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );} 
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] ); 
  } else 
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false ); 
}
addEvent(document, 'click', function(){
```

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using jQuery?

Comment: as far as I can tell, `addEvent(document.getElementById("myDiv"), 'click', function(){alert();})` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to work:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/MT3ye/

Comment: I think there were other things on the page preventing it. It works now. Thanks for confirming it Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery way.

```
$("#objId").click(function(){ doSomething();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you ...

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
$("#element_id").click ( function(){  ... } );
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using the

```
addEvent($('#id'), 'click', function(){
```

Comment: would work but you need `addEvent($('#id')[0], 'click', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('id')` instead of `document`.
You should have a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript